# Set up OpenCL with intel graphics 4400 on arch linux?

Tags: gpu, opencl, intel, archlinux, manjaro

I would like to enable OpenCL for GPU Computing on my laptop.
**Its specs are the following:**

- OS: Manjaro ( Archlinux )
- CPU / GPU: Core-i7 4600U / Intel Graphics 4400

**I'm really new to this. What I did so far is to install all required dependencies as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GPGPU#OpenCL_Development) including:**

- intel-opencl
- ocl-icd
- clinfo

**Executing  `clinfo` returns the following output:**

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) OpenCL
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel(R) Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_icd cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_spir
  Platform Extensions function suffix             INTEL

  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) OpenCL
Number of devices                                 2
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) HD Graphics
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 
  Driver Version                                  r5.0.63503
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               20
  Max clock frequency                             1100MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     0
    Supported partition types                     by <unknown> (0x563e00000000)
    Supported affinity domains                    (n/a)
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             256x256x256
  Max work group size                             256
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Please notice the last line. 
I'm on a german working station so the last line stating a memory access error. I don't know how to fix it. 
 Any advices would be really nice. 
Thanks in advance :-)

**EDIT:**
The exactly error message in english is: 
`segmentation error`
Maybe that helps for further solutions...

Answer (score 0):

It usually means some inconsistency between various pieces of hardware/software on your box. You have one platform (which is normal) with two devices - the first device has `GPU` type, but the `clinfo` couldn't request info about second device, which is probably your CPU.

I think you should develop a number of simple C/C++ programs to mimic what the `clinfo` does. It'll be very educational - anyway it's a first step any OpenCL program begin from. Use Khronos online manual:

- [clGetPlatformIds](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformIDs.html) - to get list of platforms
- [clGetPlatformInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformInfo.html) - to request info about a platform
- [clDeviceIds](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceIDs.html) - to get list of devices for a particular platform
- [clGetDeviceInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) - to request info about a device
- and so on...

Hopefully, it will help you.

Comment: thanks for drawing my attention to that it's not the GPU but the CPU having problems here. Unfortunately all opencl programs I tried so far gave me the exact same error message at some point. Always segmentation error...

Comment: @Chris - if even a simplest OpenCL program crashes, then it looks like the system setup problem. You can trace what files/libraries are loaded during your program execution - do you have something like `strace` on your system (I'm on Xubuntu)? You might have incorrectly set paths... Or mix of libraries from different suppliers